# php storm 2018 and symfony 3.4

Tags: symfony

I got this error message when I tried to use symfony 3.4 with phpstorm 2018

[Settings | Tools | Command Line Tool Support ] -> add -> tool based on Symfony Console

Problem

> Failed to parse output as xml: Error on line 2: Content is not allowed in prolog..
>   Command
>   C:\xampp\php\php.exe C:\xampp\htdocs\symfony\bin\console list --format=xml
>   Output
>
> Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\symfony\bin/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\symfony\bin\console on line 15
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\symfony\bin/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\symfony\bin\console on line 15

Comment: You're missing `autoload.php` file. It looks like you didn't install dependencies with `composer install` command.

Comment: sorry i'm new ,how can I install composer and the dependencies. thanks

Comment: Did you create this project on your own? If so, you should already have composer installed and you would need just to use it. If somehow you don't have Composer yet, check it's website for instructions on how to install it. https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md

Comment: I have installed  xampp. In which folder I  should install composer?

Comment: It depends on your preference. Check the link I've provided in previous comment.